# Why is the category of posets defined as it is?

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

When defining the category of all posets, one says that morphisms are order-preserving functions. However, one can allow order-reversing functions too, since composition is well-behaved (composition of monotone functions is monotone, regardless they preserve or reverse order).

I was wondering if there is any historical/theoretical reason behind.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio But I think they mean, why don't we *also* allow order-reversing functions. The composition of (weakly/strictly) (monotone/antitone) functions is again a (weakly/strictly) (monotone/antitone) function

Comment: Yes, sorry. I mean order-preserving and order-reversing functions, together.

Comment: Probably because an order reversing map $P\to Q$ is an order-preserving map $P\to Q^{op}.$ Treating order preserving and reversing as the same "type" of map seems to obscure rather than reveal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that order-preserving-ness is a particular instance of a much more general phenomenon: namely, that of a **homomorphism** between two relational structures. By contrast, order-reversing-ness is really specific to the case of a binary relation - what does "order-reversing" mean in the context of a relation with three inputs?

The "specialize-from-relational-structures" theme also lets us cook up the category you have in mind. Given a poset $\mathcal{P}=(P;\le)$, consider the relations $R(x,y,z,w)$ and $C(a,b)$ on $P$ given by $$R=\{(x,y,z,w): (x\le y\leftrightarrow z\le w)\wedge (y\le x\leftrightarrow w\le z)\}$$ and $$C=\{(a,b): a\le b\vee b\le a\}.$$

The "forgetting" process $\mathcal{P}\leadsto\mathcal{P}^-$ gives rise to a category whose objects are the "$\{R,C\}$-structures" coming from posets and whose morphisms are "$\{R,C\}$-preserving" maps.

*On a technical level, we might worry that this resulting category is somehow more complicated than the original category of posets it comes from, but in an important sense it isn't: $R$ and $C$ are built from $\le$ in a "nicely-definable" way, and this together with some other more technical observations tells us that at least from the perspective of **model theory** everything is reasonably nice here. I'm not going to go into detail about this here, but if you're interested look up the notion of "model-theoretic reducts" - the introduction of [Junker/Ziegler](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27590302) is a good starting point, and also helps motivate the general study of such processes beyond this particular example.*

Crucially, this "poset-derived" category is **just the category you have in mind but renamed**. That is:

> If $\mathcal{P},\mathcal{Q}$ are posets and $f:P\rightarrow Q$ is a function on their underlying sets, then the following are equivalent:
>
> - $f$ is the underlying-set-function of a homomorphism $\mathcal{P}^-\rightarrow\mathcal{Q}^-$.
> - $f$ is **either** order-preserving or order-reversing.

All of this is decent evidence, in my opinion, that the classical idea that homomorphisms should preserve relations is "good enough" - even when we want something broader, such as your category, we can often fit it into this framework in a clear and simple way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did a little bit of model theory a long time ago and I believe I see your point. Actually it seems to me a clarification of Thomas Andrews comment: I'm just complicating things which are easier, as a matter of facts. Your answer explains in what sense I'm complicating them. Thank you, and sorry for my bad English!